# Docusign_rest how to send custom pdf as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, pdf, prawn, docusignapi

I have done docusign_rest. creating template and envelope too. so now my question is how can I generate my pdf while sending document with Docusign? PDF not to be saved if this done then that's good enough to pass for me.

```
We are passing path: 'pdf.pdf', name: 'pdf.pdf'
```

I want to pass PDF but not as static way. is it possible?

I tried a lot but it gives me error of path. So can you tell me how to get global or dynamic path for file?

```
@dum = Dum.find(params[:id])
@pdf = DumPdf.new(@dum)
send_data @pdf.render
```

This codes generates my PDF. How can I get file path in rails 3?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, please clarify your question.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: updated my question. want pdf dynamic not static from specific path. path could be dynamic as user wants.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby the File.New() method creates a file in the current working directory of your program.    To find the current working directory you can do

```
puts Dir.pwd # This will return something like /usr/bin
```

That will give you the directory path and if you append the filename to this then you have the full path of your file.  To check if the dynamic file path that you've constructed is valid you can check if your file exists, with

```
# This returns either true or false
File.file?( "document.pdf" )
```

Once you have the path of your dynamic file you can read those file bytes and put them into your DocuSign API request.  The DocuSign API doesn't care where the bytes come from as long as they are valid file bytes encoded correctly.